# Serve scaled image for web

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have the "serve scaled image" issue when I test my website with http://gtmetrix.com/

For example, my image size is 2000x3000 and the recommendation is 104x104px (I set the width and height of img to 104x104px in my css). I tried to resize all my icon images to 104x104. However, those images look blurry? I thought it should not be blurry because the size is correct.

My question is how do I know the size to scale the image when 
 1. img has fix size (I set the width and height of img to 104x104px in my css) => blurry issue
 2. responsive image

I use Wordpress, any free plugin that solves the issue. I used optimole but it makes my images blurry!

Thanks,

Comment: You should really look into the scrset hooks/filters. This is a really long read, but is quite helpful: https://alexwright.net/blog/web-design/responsive-images-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

Use css properties such as

```
object-fit: cover
```

for image tag and

```
background-size: cover /* it can be contain too, depending on the situation */
```

for backgrounded images

Comment: I already used them. It's not about the image scaled wrongly but it blury

Answer (score 0):

Use "picture" HTML tag for different window widths:

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="/img/blog/responsive-images-lg.png 730w">
    <source srcset="/img/blog/responsive-images-md.png 610w">
    <source srcset="/img/blog/responsive-images-sm.png 350w">
    <img src="/img/blog/reponsive-images.png" alt="responsive images" class="img-fluid rounded">
</picture>
```